# Redirecting from google maps to my application?

Tags: java, android

Need to redirect from default google maps to my application when source location and destination location are equal

I am moving from my application to google maps like this but i am unable to come back to my application from google maps.

```
intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                    Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=17.464600,78.366630&daddr=17.450970,78.381660"));
            startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you can do this since google map does not have a reference to your app. I did something similar. I used this.

```
<fragment
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            tools:context="Your Context"
            tools:openDrawer="start">
</fragment>
```

You can see this [LINK](https://demonuts.com/android-google-map-in-fragment/). This tutorial seems to be pretty good. It worked for me.